# Science behind mantras

Tags: mantras, science

What is the science behind the working of mantras and strotams ?

Assuming god to be dual, especially , how is it possible for god to understand human emotion and respond to that. How is the chanting of any mystic syllable or om namah ‘ name of the lord’ work as a subtle science in our life?

Thank you